# Running an app minimized on a system with a minimal X server

Tags: x11, window-management

I run X on Ubuntu minimal using `xinit`. I now want to launch spotify in minimized mode as it's remotely controlled and I don't want it to be visible.

I also thought about installing a small window manager, but I have to be able to minimize the window through a script, because there is neither a keyboard nor a mouse available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with:

```
xdotool windowunmap <window-id>
```

Thanks to Chris Brown for pointing me towards using xdotool. Seems like minimizing a window is only possible if there is a window manager running. But unmapping works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xdotool` with `windowminimize`. Assuming that it is the active window:

```
xdotool windowminimize "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
```

If it isn't the active window, you can use `xdotool search Spotify` to get the window. If this doesn't work, you can use `xprop` to find the WM_CLASS of the Spotify window, and use that instead.